# Bettering the Generic SeekBar Example

Tags: java, android, seekbar

This code and minor variations thereof exist in many forums on the net. When I launch it on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 4.1.1), the bar appears, the thumb can be moved, the position is reported, etc. All good, EXCEPT, the thumb never disappears. Mine manifests as a little blue circle, which I can slide along a bar, but it leaves a trail of "thumbs" behind it: one at each of the possible integer locations in the range of the seekbar.

Is the code incomplete? Is there something we have to add to manually redraw the component?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FullscreenActivity
    extends Activity
    implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        //  Notify that the progress level has changed.
        textView.setText(textView.getText()+"\n"+"SeekBar now at the value of:"+progress);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // placeholder
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // placeholder
    }

}
```

Here's the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:max="31"
        android:progress="15" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Screenshot of the effect:

[image: screenshot of the effect]

***Update*** The effect is the same on a ZTE-BLADE running Android 2.2. Of course teh default graphic is different (the gray / orange seekbar with a more square "thumb") but the thumbs remain behind at all the points I've scrolled through.

The residual garbage clears if I change the screen orientation, which makes me think it just needs a redraw. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

So, I copied and pasted my example code line-at-a-time into a new project, running it as I went, hoping to find the line which failed.

Got the whole thing pasted in and it worked perfectly. No problems in the seekbar.

On comparing the projects, the only difference was that the AndroidManifest.XML file contained the line

```
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
```

in the activity section. So, I went back to my original (faulty) project and took this line out. Now the project works fine.

I have my answer: the code is complete and there's nothing we need to add to make it redraw.

I still don't understand why this line had that effect and now I have a horrible white background when I wanted black.